# Jenkins sends unnecessary email to all developers for a failed build

Tags: jenkins

I am building our SVN trunk repository every hour. I have configured Jenkins to send emails to those developers who broke the build. For some reason, Jenkins seems to send email to any developer who has *ever* at any point committed to SVN. I would expect Jenkins to send emails only to those who have broken the build, i.e. those developers who have committed code between a successful build and the failed build. Now it seems that all our developers get sent an email for every failed build.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your "Source Code Management" also set for the Jenkins built in SVN or you do it yourself?

Comment: I am using the Jenkins built in SVN v. 1.43 to update the workspace

Comment: Hmm my builds have been only either Unstable or Failed. Does the recipients list get cleared only after the build has been successful? It has never been Successful.

Comment: That might be your problem! Try editing the build to exit with 0 once and run it. After that, allow the build to run and fail again. Also, is your trigger based on SCM polling?

Comment: Ok I will try that. Yes, the build is triggered using SCM polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried editable email notification, where you can configure for failure, unstable or any other kind of trigger.[image]

Comment: I have, but I am unsure if it solves my problem because I would like it to work like this: when a build fails it stores the committers, and continues to send to those until the build is Unstable. This clears the committers list and when the build goes back to Failed, the committers counter starts rolling again. In my current setup, the committers list seems to clear only after build goes to Successful, but I need to to clear after build goes to Unstable too.

Comment: Configure only failure and improved triggers. Remove the unstable trigger from the list.